# Gitlab Runner Pending Job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

When ever I am trying to execute the jobs of a pipeline, The first Job is getting executed but the second job is under pending state. How to overcome this?

Note: I have active gitlab runner.

Comment: SHow your gitlab CI file or at least the second jobs definition, does it havea tag that the runner doesnt have so there is no runners available that meet those tag requirements?

Comment: Yeah,the tags were not matching so thats why i got the error. Thanks @ChrisDoyle